# How to go through hundreds of arrays in a single document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm reposing this question as I'm adding a clearer title and more info in the post. Currently, my MongoDB consists of hundreds of individual arrays in one document (only one _id element) and within those arrays is where all my data lies (screenshot is in the image below).

[image]

There is a data set inside each array called "winnings" which shows the total winnings for each player.

[image: The actual data that is within each array.]

So the schema for the MongoDB is like this:

```
[{
Date: "01/01/2012",
Entry ($): "2",
Id: "123456",
Link: "www.mywebsite.com",
Opponent: "Opponent"
}]
```

It also seems that all these arrays only have one MongoDB unique id attached to them:

[image]

So, I believe, all my data that is stored in all these arrays are located in only one document that is associated with only one MongoDB _id.

How would I aggregate through all of these sets to get the sum of the winnings?

I tried MongoDB's aggregation method via the $sum operator via $group methods, but it doesn't work. This is the closest thing I can think of:

```
Collection.find().forEach(function(){

return db.Collection.aggregate([
{ $group: {Date:"$Date", total:{$sum:"$Winnings ($)"}}},
])

})
```

But obviously it doesn't work. I haven't found one method that can iterate through only one document and hundreds of arrays. Trying to fit in parseInt inside the forEach function looks like a nightmare as well and surely is not accepted in MongoDB without the $with statement. Not even sure if forEach is even appropriate for this. Going through each array individually like this is what confuses me right now.

Comment: You cannot apply query criteria for a subdocument or array within a document. Use an unwind operator to flatten the document and then aggregate it. Include a sample input and output data in your question if you need help with the query...

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: aggregate isn't recognized as a function. I'm running version 2.6 of Mongo.

Comment: Keeping everything in one document is essentially like keeping it in a flat file (ok, in meteor you get to synchronize it between server->client ).  So for iterating it, you are not restricted to the mongo api.  You can use map-reduce style processing, e.g. using the underscore library.  However @KG32 is right, think about changing your schema and let the database help you out here!

Comment: Hey @JeremyK, thanks for your input. I completely forgot about that. You helped me solve my issue. If you want, you can post it in the comment section below so I can upvote you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `Collection` with a single document containing an array with many items in it is like a using a (json) file as your storage.  The main benefit you get (by using a `Collection`) is Meteor makes it easy to synchronize the data between the server and the client(s).

So for processing the (json array) data, you are not restricted to the mongo api. You can implement `map-reduce` style processing using any javascript you like, though I'd suggest using the [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) library that comes already bundled with meteor-core.

However as others have mentioned at some point it will probably be better to split the document up (e.g. to use the mongo query api, to send filtered datasets to clients, easier updates).  In this case process the csv file line by line, with each line being inserted into the db, all with a common `documentId` field.

**Papa.parse** (untested):

This should split your data into one db document per row of the csv file.

```
var docId = new Mongo.ObjectID()._str;
Papa.parse(file, {
  complete: function(results) {
    results.data.forEach(row){
      row.docId = docId;
      MyCollection.insert(row);
    }  
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man. I use Papa Parse to parse the document. I will have to check and see how I could make it process in a way where I can actually use the MongoDB api.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var db = Collection.findOne();
    var winningsSum = 0;
    for(x in db) {
        if(db.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
            if(x!='_id') {  // it's necessary to skip _id, otherwise it returns NaN 
                winningsSum += db[x].winnings;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(winningsSum); //sum of winnings
```

Comment: I recreated your database and it works. Hope I didn't get something wrong though, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It gives me 0 as a result. Also, if you don't mind, what's the purpose of `hasOwnProperty` in your solution. All entries in the file are strings. Thanks.

Comment: Ok then, I guess I did something wrong while trying to replicate your database, I'll check it again. And about hasOwnProperty, it lets you know if a property is directly on an instance of an object or inherited from it's prototype chain. It's safer this way, especially since I'm trying to find a solution for a database I don't know everything about.

Comment: Ok, thanks man. You helped me quite a bit as well. I think the problem is that the numbers in my database aren't actually numbers, they are strings. So using Number(string) would probably be a solution.

Comment: Oh, right, didn't notice, stupid but crucial detail. That's why it worked on my database. I didn't manage to test it yesterday, but from other comments I figured you fixed it. Anyway, if it's still not working, I'd be happy to try to help

Answer (score 0):

You should consider placing items as separate documents. MongoDB iterates way faster over documents than an array of objects in a single document. Also, it's much simpler, it's a good practice and it's a must when setting up publications and subscriptions.

Comment: That's not possible, I don't think. I'm having the user upload a .csv file, then it gets parsed into JSON format. Unfortunately, the results end up being in arrays under one document.

Comment: It's possible.  Loop over each row in the csv and `Collection.insert(ConvertToJSON(rowData + CommonDocumentId))`.  Add a common document id to each row so you can retrieve the set of documents that belong to one file.